# Vaadin set background color for selected row in a grid

Tags: java, html, css, vaadin

I'm new in vaadin development and i hope someone can help me. I just created a grid table with a model and everything works fine. But now, i want to change the background color of the selected row. I figure out, that i have to create a theme. I found this in the Vaadin Forum: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17867059/how-to-set-selected-row-opacity-in-vaadin-grid

This is what i have already done:

1. I created a html class with the code from the link. I called this class grid-selection-theme.html
2. I put this class into src/main/webapp/frontend/styles/grid-selection-theme.html
3. In the java file with the Grid, i added the import: @HtmlImport("frontend://styles/grid-selection-theme.html);
4. I added the theme to the grid: mygrid.addThemeName("grid-selection-theme");

Here is the code from the other thread in the forum:

```
<dom-module id="grid-header" theme-for="vaadin-grid">
  <template>
    <style>
        :host(:not([reordering])) [part~="row"][selected] [part~="body-cell"]:not([part~="details-cell"]) {
                background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .50);
        }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Which Vaadin version you use? Your approach is valid for Vaadin 10 - 13, but with 14 there is a change.

Comment: Could you check if you have any 404 errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me, what is your version of framework?

In case you are using Vaadin 14, you would need to place styles into `.css` file instead and import the file using `@CSSImport`

1. My style file `gridStyles.css` contains:

```
:host([theme~="grid-selection-theme"]) [part~="row"][selected] [part~="body-cell"]:not([part~="details-cell"]) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

2. Class where grid is used has this import defined:
   `@CssImport(value = "./styles/gridStyles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")`
3. Grid has theme name added

I've change a `host` selector to reflect a theme attribute: in case you have multiple grids on the same page, then style will be applied only to the one having `mygrid.addThemeName("grid-selection-theme");`

Output looks like this:
[image]